# How to stop Progress Dialog after loading webpage

Tags: android

In this code, I am trying to move from activity to webView using Progress Dialog but Progress Dialog is not stopping after loading website why? 
Is anyone helps me?

> Instead of using onLoadResource I used  onPreExecute but it's not working.

```
public class ProgressTask extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        //Get webview
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        startWebView("http://goodmorningretail.com/mgmretail/index.php");
    }



    private void startWebView(String url) {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            //Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProgressTask.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try{
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

// Javascript inabled on webview
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Other webview options

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);


    }

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason sometimes calling isShowing() on ProgressDialog objects returns false, even thought the dialog is showing. Instead of checking for isShowing(), just check that it's not null (although you're catching exception anyway....), and then call progressDialog.dismiss().